# Dates in Ruby On Rails and MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, date

There is collection with Timestamp

```
"timestamp" : ISODate("2014-06-10T00:00:00Z"),
```

But

```
coll.find(:timestamp=>"ISODate(\"2014-06-10T00:00:00Z\")
```

don't return results. With _id and other params it works good. I tryed to use different date format but it always returns empty array. In console command

```
db.my_collection.find({timestamp: ISODate("2014-06-10T00:00:00Z")})
```

returns right results.

How I can get data in ROR with this param?

P.S.Excuse me for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to use `Date` type to define time.

```
coll.find(:timestamp=>Date.new(2014,06,10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're querying MongoDB for a String when you do

```
coll.find(:timestamp => "ISODate(\"2014-06-10T00:00:00Z\")
```

Instead, use an actual `Time` object in your query

```
require 'time'
coll.find(:timestamp => Time.parse('2014-06-10T00:00:00Z'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use method mongoize with MongoId.
Like this:

```
(Date.today-30.days).mongoize
```

Or

```
example_day.to_date.mongoize
```

For more detail see it in here:
[Mongoid aggregation $match with Date objects not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752215/mongoid-aggregation-match-with-date-objects-not-working/43238289#43238289)